# WSO2 - Micro-integrator - Connects to Dashboard , but no integrator instances found. But intergator istance exist and connected

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Enviroment:

Server Almalinux 8.7
java: java-11-openjdk-11.0.17.0.8-2.el8_6.x86_64
Micro integrator installed (4.1.0) Micro Integrator Dashboard installed (4.1.0)

The micro-integrator connects to the Dashboard, but when I try to login, the dashboard says "No running micro integrator instances found. Pls start a server a login":

The MI runs after the dashboard. The dashboard registers de MI as per below log line, but when I try to login it says that no MI is running....
New node dev_node_2 in group : mi_dev is registered. Inserting heartbeat information ERROR {LoginDelegate} - No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login.

I verified  the default "-DenableManagementApi=true" system parameter value in micro-integrator.sh.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The MI node might not be registering its hostname properly. Along with the dashboard url, please try configuring MI's hostname and port as well.

```
[dashboard_config]
dashboard_url = "https://{hostname/ip}:{port}/dashboard/api/"
management_hostname = "<HOST_NAME>"
management_port = <PORT>
```

Comment: Which is management port, http or https?

Comment: I added hostname, tried both http and https ports, dashboard also logged mi connection: `INFO {HeartBeatDelegate} - New node dev_node_2 in group : mi_dev is registered. Inserting heartbeat information`; but the login still error

Comment: I added management_hostname and management_port, but thr resul is the same.  **ERROR {LoginDelegate} - No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login.**